# offline_access deprecation and scenarios 3 and 4

Tags: oauth, facebook-oauth

Every time I read https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/, I'm left more confused than the time before. I'm looking for some clarification on some items under scenarios 3 and 4 (server-side apps and client-side apps)

For server-side apps, it states "If the call is made while there is still a valid 60-day access_token for that user, the returned access_token from this second call may be the same or may have changed, but in either case the expiration time will be a fresh 60 days."

- What is "the call" that is referred to here?
- Is it the same exchange of an authorization code for the access token that takes place during the initial OAuth flow?
- Or is it the endpoint call described under the client-side section to freshen the token to 60 days?
- If it's the former, then where does the authorization code come from when trying to renew the token?
- Is it the same authorization code from the original callback or do I have to go through the authorization flow again?

In short, can a server-side app keep freshening the life of a 60-day token and, if so then how?

Regarding client-side use, the document indicates that the client must make that endpoint call passing in (among other things) the application's client ID and client secret.

- My interpretation of "client-side" may be wrong, but I'm thinking in terms of a JavaScript-based client running in a web-browser.
- If that's what Facebook has in mind here, then should the JavaScript code really ever know about the client secret? (It won't be much of a secret if it's sent to the client.)

Even then, it indicates that 60-day tokens cannot have their life extended and that a new 2-hour token must first be acquired and used to get a 60-day token. This is under the client-side portion of the document, but does this rule apply to server-side 60-day tokens, too? If not, then I ask again: How do I freshen the life of a 60-day token on the server-side?

Finally, the question that has been burning in my mind for some time: Why has Facebook adopted this strategy and not adopted the refresh token as defined in the OAuth 2 specification (a specification that Facebook is helping define)???

EDIT: Further thoughts/questions after re-reading the document again:

At the beginning it says "a long-lived expiration time that can be renewed each time the user revists your app". My initial assumption is that the way to renew it would be to make a call to the endpoint later in the document. But, aside from the fact that the endpoint is described under the "client-side" heading, it also states "Please note, the endpoint can only be used to extend the short-lived user access_tokens. If you pass an access_token that had a long-lieved expiration time, the endpoint will simply pass that same access_token back to you without altering or extending the expiration time." (The typo on "long-lieved" is from FB's own documentation.)

Okay, so if that endpoint cannot be used to renew the expiration time (and my own attempts to renew a long-lived token with that endpoint prove this out), then how can I renew the expiration time on a long-lived token each time they visit my app?

Is there no one who understands how this is supposed to work?

Comment: I do have the same doubts you have. I was so glad I found this question but all my happiness fall apart when I found no one has answered this yet. I don't know if it's me or Facebook is really bad writing documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Facebook's doc (like for the 5th time) and with the help of [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132610/how-to-handle-facebooks-deprecation-of-offline-access-when-you-use-token-both-i) this are my conclusions.

> What is "the call" that is referred to here?

It referres to the OAuth call to get an access token.

> Is it the same exchange of an authorization code for the access token
>   that takes place during the initial OAuth flow?

Yes, I believe it's that flow.

> Or is it the endpoint call described under the client-side section to
>   freshen the token to 60 days?

No, that endpoint is only valid for short-lived access tokens.

> Is it the same authorization code from the original callback or do I
>   have to go through the authorization flow again?

You've to go through the authorization flow again.

> how can I renew the expiration time on a long-lived token each time
>   they visit my app?

Long-lived access tokens cannot be renewed using the client side endpoint. The user will have to reauthorize the app to get a new one. 
According to Facebook documentation:

> If the call (OAuth authorization call) is made while there is still a valid long-lived user
>   access_token for that user, the returned user access_token from this
>   second call may be the same or may have changed, but in either case
>   the expiration time will be set to a long expiration time.

Once the application is reauthorized you'll get a new expiration time. Facebook may return a new long-lived access token, so you should grab it and replace that information for the one you already had.

Conclusion:
Seems there's no way to renew a long-lived access token without user intervention. To get a new expiration time/access token they'll have to reauthorize your app. My humble advice is  that should suggest the user to reauthorize it, a few days before the expiration date.
Also, this [Facebook how-to](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/) can came in handy for checking expired access tokens.